# LINQ getting distinct records based on an item value

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have following LINQ query

```
 var unallocatedOrders = (from orderLine in context.OrderLineItemDboes
     where (orderLine.Status == unallocated || orderLine.Status == null)
         && orderLine.orderline.order.order_status_fk == verified
     group orderLine
         by new { orderLine.orderline.ol_id,orderLine.orderline.order.order_id }
         into g
     select new { OrderLineId = g.Key.ol_id, Count = g.Count(), OrderId = g.Key.order_id })
 .ToList();
```

Above query giving me results in the following way

```
Order1 ol1 2
order1 ol2 3
order1 ol3 1
order2 ol1 1
order2 ol2 2
order3 ol1 4
order3 ol2 3
order3 ol3 2
```

I need to iterate through the above list based on order ids and need to fetch corresponding lines and quantity. 
I need to get this line id and quantity to a Dictionary.
Can somebody suggest how can I get it done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can select the items using GroupBy.  (Your question doesn't really specify how you want to use the lines, so I just output them to the Debug console.)

```
// group by the OrderId
foreach (var group in unallocatedOrders.GroupBy(row => row.OrderId))
{
    Debug.WriteLine(

        // for each line, output "Order x has lines y1, y2, y3..."
        string.Format("Order {0} has lines {1}", 

            // here the key is the OrderId
            group.Key,

            // comma-delimited output
            string.Join(", ", 

                // select each value in the group, and output its OrderLineId, and quantity
                group.Select(item => 
                    string.Format("{0} (quantity {1})", item.OrderLineId, item.Count)
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

---

You can get a dictionary lookup by using `ToDictionary`.

```
// two-level lookup: 1) OrderId 2) OrderLineId
var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, long>>();

foreach (var group in unallocatedOrders.GroupBy(row => row.OrderId))
{
    // add each order to the lookup
    lookup.Add(group.Key, group.ToDictionary(

        // key selector 
        keySelector: item => item.OrderLineId,

        // value selector
        elementSelector: item => item.Count()
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can I get this OrderLineId and Count to a Dictionary<long,int>?

Comment: @Naresh Do you mean like a `Dictionary<int,Dictionary<long,int>>`, where the first is the order lookup, and the second lets you look up the count by line number?